An equality between $\pi$ and $\Gamma$ function
Consider the following equality:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{(\frac{(2n-3)!!}{(2n-2)!!})^2*\frac{\pi}{2}}{n}=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})^2}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}-\frac{2\sqrt{2}*\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})^2}$$
With $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$
How to prove this equality?

How does this equality arise?

By using intuition and chatGPT.

What is the intuition?

Your question is answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2156355/integral-int-01-frac-sqrt1-x41x2dx?noredirect=1

Note that ChatGPT is dumb in mathematics. If you want to discover new mathematics, you need to learn mathematics. Get a bachelor degree, and then a PhD degree in mathematics. Read books. An earlier question of yours revealed that you are not familiar with the residue theorem, which is one the most basic tools in mathematics. You cannot ask research level questions until you are familiar with the basics.

Your series is a special case of Gauss' hypergeometric series. In standard notation, it is
$${}_2F_1\left(\begin{matrix}1/2,1/2\\2\end{matrix};-1\right).$$
In standard tables (e.g. 15.4.26 in https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4) you find the summation formula
$${}_2F_1\left(\begin{matrix}a,b\\a-b+1\end{matrix};-1\right)=\frac{\Gamma(a-b+1)\Gamma(a/2+1)}{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(a/2-b+1)}.$$
You series is contiguous to this one; you can write it as
\begin{multline*}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1/2)_n(1/2)_n}{(1)_n(2)_n}\,(-1)^n\times(2(n+1)-(2n+1))\\
=2\,{}_2F_1\left(\begin{matrix}1/2,1/2\\1\end{matrix};-1\right)
-{}_2F_1\left(\begin{matrix}1/2,3/2\\2\end{matrix};-1\right),\end{multline*}
where the series on the right are of the form above. This should give your right-hand side.
